# Photo orientation in imageView with Samsung mobile phone

Tags: java, android, imageview, samsung-mobile, onactivityresult

I have a problem with the image on Samsung device
Each time I take a photograph the vertical form but when it calls an image of the gallery the classroom
Vertically
It programmed with class ExifInterface and I can not find result

Every time I take a picture I call my class PreviewImage which is where I show the image
Subsequently I have the button that takes me to assign the profile photo I have this method onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
            int exif = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            switch (exif) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    orientation = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    orientation = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    orientation = 270;
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("tmessages", e.toString());
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PhotoViewer.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PHOTO_PATH, photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PHOTO_ORIENTATION, orientation);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PHOTO_EDIT, false);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 10);

    }
```

And this is my PhotoViewer class

```
   private void sendPicture() {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();  
        returnIntent.putExtra("photoDescription", photoDescription.getText().toString());
        returnIntent.putExtra("photoPath", localPath);
        returnIntent.putExtra("orientation", orientation);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

Once the photo is taken it returns me to the onActivityResult method of the Profile class from where it was called

```
else if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (photoFile != null&&LoginController.getInstance().xmppConnection.isConnected()) {
            byte[] photo = AndroidUtilities
                    .createProfileImage(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
            ProfileManager.getInstance().publishPhoto( photo);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length);
            avatar.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,R.string.LabelProfilePhotoFailed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

How can I make the image show me vertical in the profile photo?

Comment: Can you please use phrases like 'portrait' and 'landscape' instead of 'vertical'. Your question is not clear. Can you please review and change it as you are saying you want to show the image vertical, your comment says its already showing vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done half the job! Just use the orientation you calculated before :

```
else if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    if (photoFile != null&&LoginController.getInstance().xmppConnection.isConnected()) {
        byte[] photo = AndroidUtilities
                .createProfileImage(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
        ProfileManager.getInstance().publishPhoto( photo);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length);
 ->     decodedByte = rotate(decodedByte, orientation);
        avatar.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,R.string.LabelProfilePhotoFailed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

When **orientation** = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(EXTRA_PHOTO_ORIENTATION).

```
private static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bm, int rotation) {
    if (rotation != 0) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotation);
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return bmOut;
    }
    return bm;
}
```

Comment: Hello friend first of all thanks for the help that has created the method to turn

private Bitmap rotate(Bitmap decodedByte, int orientation) {
        orientation = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(EXTRA_PHOTO_ORIENTATION);
        return decodedByte;
    }
But to a I do not get the correct rotation that grows that I keep failing?

Comment: Friend really thanks, one more question? How could I control at any given moment if I take the horizontal photograph and the photograph remains vertical? Thanks to the method that you provided me the vertical photo and that was what I wanted, but do a test taking the photo in landscape mode and I broke the image do you have any idea what that may be? Beforehand thank you very much.

Comment: Try to add this line : getContentResolver().notifyChange(photoFile, null); before using ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(photoFile.getAbsolutePath()); If my answer helped you, could you please upvote or accept my answer :) ?